# how would you sanitize '$' and '/' in string (java)

Tags: java, string, design-patterns

Having difficulty sanitizing the string to allow $ and / to stay within the string. (i.e. would like to accept names/emails to keep the dollar sign). To do this, I was attempting to use the Pattern class and I'm trying to find the best solution to place the Pattern method in the public String cutomiseText.

//Original Code that works:

```
public String customiseText(String bodyText, List<Object> objectList) {
    Map<String, String> replaceKeyMap = extractMapFromList(objectList);

    // iterate over the mapkey and return the body text replace
    for (final String key : replaceKeyMap.keySet()) {
        String replacementKey = "(?i)" + key;
        String replacementValue = replaceKeyMap.get(key);
        if (replacementValue == null) {
            replacementValue = "";
        }
        bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll(replacementKey, replacementValue);
    }

    return bodyText;
}
```

// Code that does not work:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String customiseText(String bodyText, List<Object> objectList) {
    Map<String, String> replaceKeyMap = extractMapFromList(objectList);
    String escapedString = Pattern.quote(bodyText); //
    // iterate over the mapkey and return the body text replace
    for (final String key : replaceKeyMap.keySet()) {
        String replacementKey = "(?i)" + key; // not case sensitive and empty string matcher
        String replacementValue = replaceKeyMap.get(key);
        if (replacementValue == null) {
            replacementValue = "";
        }
        escapedString = escapedString.replaceAll(replacementKey, replacementValue);
    }

    return escapedString;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you should place the what?

Comment: Calling `Pattern.quote` on `bodyText` makes no sense. Calling it on `key` would make much more sense.

Comment: Since you're iterating both keys and values, use `entrySet()`, not `keySet()`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you showed us some sample content, and some of the patterns you're trying to use.  It's difficult to understand exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Andreas, Here is an update as you had recommended, but still doesn't work:      
        for (final String key : replaceKeyMap.keySet()) {
            Pattern patternK = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(key));
            String replacementKey = "(?i)" + patternK; // not case sensitive and empty string matcher
            String replacementValue = replaceKeyMap.get(patternK);

            if (replacementValue == null) {
                replacementValue = "";
            }
            bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll(replacementKey, replacementValue);
        }

Comment: I meant `String replacementKey = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote(key)`.  --- And we still have no idea what this question is about. You mention $ and /, but your code has nothing to do with that. If you're referring to the *replacement* value, then $ and \ are the issue, and you use `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with going back to the original code and added one line to sanitize the $ / :

```
// iterate over the mapkey and return the body text replace
for (final String key : replaceKeyMap.keySet()) {
    String replacementKey = "(?i)" + key;
    String replacementValue = replaceKeyMap.get(key);
    if (replacementValue == null) {
        replacementValue = "";
    }
    *replacementValue = replacementValue.replace("\\",     
        "\\\\").replace("$","\\$"); // sanitizes '$' and '\'* //only added this
    bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll(replacementKey, replacementValue);
}

return bodyText;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is that both `key` and `value` are plain text, not regular expresssions, you have to escape (aka "quote") them.

**Note:** Changed code to use `entrySet`.

```
public String customiseText(String bodyText, List<Object> objectList) {
    Map<String, String> replaceKeyMap = extractMapFromList(objectList);

    // iterate over the mapkey and return the body text replace
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : replaceKeyMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote(entry.getKey());
        String value = entry.getValue();
        value = (value != null ? Matcher.quoteReplacement(value) : "");
        bodyText = bodyText.replaceAll(key, value);
    }
    return bodyText;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused (because I'm a newbie at this - my apologies). It looks like I will have to establish the getKey() and getValue() methods here. Also, what class will I need to import to allow Entry<String, String> to be accepted?... Also, this java file was working fine with the original code - I thought this would be an easier fix just to get the dollar sign as a string without error. Is this not possible?

Comment: @user5261902 `Entry` is an inner class of `Map`. Since you already imported `Map`, you can change the code to `Map.Entry` and you won't need another import. `getKey()` and `getValue()` are methods of `Entry`, so you don't have to establish them.

Comment: @user5261902 What do you mean "easier"? You're just wrapping the key with `Pattern.quote` and the value with `Matcher.quoteReplacement`. That's pretty easy.

Comment: You are correct - this is easy. Just finding the answer on my own was not so easy :( ... Also, just hit the endpoint on postman to see if this code works, but finding the same error message on that file, any suggestions?: `Exception while sending HSETEMP_SIGNUP email out to hi@google.com
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
 at com.hs.api.util.FieldMapper.customiseText(FieldMapper.java:69)` .. etc

Comment: Different question. And post stack trace when asking it.